# How do I stop prettier from formatting HTML files?

Tags: html, prettier

So the problem is that prettier does not format html very well.

for instance if I have this angular template:

```
<some-component
  some-attribute 
  [ang-binding1]='someExpr'
  [ang-binding2]='someExpr'
  (someEvent)='someFunc($event)'>
</some-component>
```

prettier will format it to something like this:

```
<some-component some-attribute [ang-binding1]='someExpr' [ang-binding2]='someExpr' (someEvent)='someFunc($event)'>
</some-component>
```

how do I disable prettier formating for html templates ?

Comment: Good question - prettier's HTML formatting is odd! For something that's supposed to encompass common standards, I haven't seen anyone format HTML at specific line lengths like it was source code before. Out of the box, it breaks every single `<p>` element.

Comment: You can no longer disable formatting in HTML files in Prettier's settings. See my answer for a workaround.

Comment: If you just want to ignore prettier for certain lines, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194864/1891625

Answer (score 43):

If you use prettier with pre-commit hook (for example, with husky), changing the editor settings will not help you.
You need to add file `.prettierignore` with the following content:

```
*.html
```

File format is similar to .gitignore. You can read more here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 38):

If you are using VS Code, you can prevent Prettier from running on HTML (or other specific languages) by adding the following to your settings:

`"prettier.disableLanguages": ["html"]`

You can find other VS Code specific options at the [`prettier/prettier-vscode` GitHub page](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode).

Comment: This does not seem to work for MySQL files. "xyz.sql". Can anyone please tell me what would be the solution for "sql" files without using `.prettierignore`.

Comment: @AnimikhAich I'm sorry, I'm not aware of Prettier's support for SQL files. I did not find any references to SQL w/in the `prettier/prettier-vscode` code base. I do see mention of a PostgreSQL plugin on the main Prettier site, but nothing for MySQL.

Comment: How do you add that to settings?

Comment: You can't do this anymore as of March 2021 - see my answer for a workaround.

Comment: Got a warning message from vscode: "This feature is no longer supported. Instead, configure VS Code"

Comment: I think this answer should be abstracted away from one particular IDE.

Answer (score 37):

If you would like to retain vscodes html formatter for `html` files, but leverage prettier for other files you can set the following in `settings.json`.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
}
```

Answer (score 32):

As of March 2021, you can no longer disable HTML in the Prettier extension settings.

[image: prettier settings]

Now, you can either use a `.prettierignore` file or use VS Code's `editor.defaultFormatter` settings, as detailed in the [Default Formatter](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#default-formatter) section of the Prettier docs.

I was able to disable Prettier (and any formatter) in HTML files by going into settings.json and changing this:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

to this:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null
  },
```

Or, you can use VS Code's default HTML formatting with this (my preferred option because forward slashes aren't added at the end of self-closing/void tags):

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
```

Comment: `null` does not work for me. Setting any other random string disables the fmt on my machine.

Comment: You legend, I used the final option you provided and it solved my problem - I hated how every HTML attribute was put on a new line! Thank you!

Comment: VSC's formatter can't get attributes wrapping right - but Prettier has this annoying self-closing vs void tag issue. *sigh*

Comment: Thank you @udondan - the whole internet is saying to set it to null, but it was still formatting my documents. The random string worked perfectly.

Answer (score 20):

And in case you want to ignore a specific line to be formatted inside file you can do that via adding `prettier-ignore` before the code.

```
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<div         class="x"       >hello world</div            >
```

Complete documentation: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 13):

If you are using VSCode, click **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** and add `"html.format.enable": false,`

Answer (score 12):

[html.format.enable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting) will turn off the default VS Code formatter. To exclude all html files in a project from being formatted you can add a **.prettierignore** file to the project root and ignore all html files.

```
*.html
```

Comment: Just a note, this will not work for vue files which have html inside the same file where ts/js and css are.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 8):

### Prettier's inline ignoring syntax

For HTML,

```
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
```

or for JSX,

```
{/* prettier-ignore */}
```

or for Javascript,

```
// prettier-ignore
```

or for CSS,

```
/* prettier-ignore */
```

**Note**: Not a direct answer to OP's question, but sometimes when one is looking to just ignore inline for specific lines, Prettier's [comment syntax](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html) is quite helpful.

Comment: In the docs there is `<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute -->` but must be applied on each line if I understand correctly. 
Is there a global document/CLI option to ignore HTML attributes only? I'd like to format elements content but not attributes.

Answer (score 5):

in addition to what was already written you can also disable formatting on save. then you would need to explicitly format the document via `CMD/CTRL + P > Format document`

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding more information to what above mentioned:

Press Ctrl + ,

Type "prettier"

Go to "Prettier: Disable Languages" option

Add "html" to it

[image]

Comment: You can't do this anymore as of March 2021 - see my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.prettierignore` file in the root of your project.
Inside the `.prettierignore` file write all files name which you want to ignore.

**Examples:**

```
# Ignore all HTML files:
*.html

#ignore for single file
login.html
file.csv

# Ignore artifacts:
build
coverage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try on your `./package.json:`

```
"scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write .js src !**.html",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, click Command + P (for Mac) to open the command palette.
Then type:

```
> settings
```

The > lets you enter VSCode commands.

From the results you can select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and this will open the settings JSON file so you can configure the settings fully. The Settings UI offers limited options.

In the settings file, add:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  }
```

That will use the VSCode formatter for html files instead of Prettier, without disabling Prettier for other files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other provided solutions, but none worked for me. After some trial and error I found the following solution that actually works:

The trick is to disable `formatOnSafe` for HTML only:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    }
}
```

Another potential blocking point is that `[html]` only refers to native HTML files. If you are using HTML templates (e.g. Django templates) those might be referred to as a different language. e.g. Django templates are called `[django-html]`.