# Prettier formatting a Vue component when I don't want it to

Tags: prettier

I've got Prettier configured to format on save.

I'm using a Vue component I got from npm to display data from an API.

```
<ExampleComponent 
    :aDynamicProp="foo"
    dataset="bar"
/>
```

The prop `dataset` is required by the component.

The issue is Prettier wants to change `dataset` to `data-set` every time I save. I imagine because it thinks i'm trying to create a HTML data attribute.

As per Prettier docs i've tried adding `<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute -->` above the component but this doesn't seem to work (perhaps because I'm triggering formatting on save, or because it's a Vue template and not HTML?).

Can anyone shed light as to how I can force Prettier to ignore the prop?

Many thanks!

Comment: if you add colon `:` like this to `:dataset` then still the prettier does the change `:data-set`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my project, which has Prettier enabled. Why do you think it's Prettier? Can you link to a GitHub repo that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @tony19 I don't have any other formatter install. Sorry can't share the repo

Comment: @Syed it didn't format it. As a work-around I'll use the semi-colon to refer to the string in the data, it's better than turning prettier off! Thank you

Comment: @bjurtown glad that this trick helped you, I have added it as my answer so pls don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: you could turn prettier off on save too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261161/how-do-i-stop-prettier-from-formatting-html-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add colon `:` to `:dataset` and that should do the trick, if it's just static string that's doing inside `dataset` then do `` :dataset="`my string`" `` with backtick `` (`) ``. If you are getting data from `data(){}`, `computed` or from `methods` as mentioned below then just do `:dataset="yourData"`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      yourData: 'Your String'
    }
  },
  // or
  computed: {
    yourData() {
      return 'Your String'
    },
  },
  // or
  methods: {
    yourData() {
      return 'Your String'
    },
  },
};
```