# Visual Studio Code removing ending slash from HTML tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have an odd environment in which when we go to production we need HTML tags to have closing slashes at the end. But VS Code *and* Atom both remove unnecessary closing slashes on save. For example,

```
<img src="..." />
```

becomes

```
<img src="..." >
```

after saving.

How do I remove this odd (and I'm sure in most cases convenient) feature? In VS Code settings I have tried disabling "HTML: Auto closing tags". I uninstalled Prettier and have no other code formatters.

My settings.json:

```
{
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
"atomKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": null,
"prettier.enable": false,
"html.format.enable": false
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691612/vscode-is-adding-space-and-slash-in-ending-tag-of-html-code-how-can-i-disable-i

Comment: If (a) your production environment needs HTML *"to have no closing slash at the end"* and (b) Visual Studio *"removes unnecessary closing slashes"*, I don't see the problem yet.

Comment: The `img` tag has no content, and isn't self closing so it _shouldn't_ have a closing `/`

Comment: @jmoerdyk: It is *allowed*, though (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags, rule 6. img is a "void element").

Comment: The formatter I use does the opposite, it makes them have closing `/`, so I suppose you could use this formatter instead. The extension on vs code is called Prettier. My html config option: `"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },`