# How to stop Prettier from using the old self closing tag syntax

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, prettier

So I recently installed prettier and whenever I save my file it adds the forwards slash in a self-closing tag. I was wondering how to stop it from doing this?

Here is what I mean:-

```
<!-- Instead of this ↓ -->
<input type="text">

<!-- It does this ↓ -->
<input type="text" />
```

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can't be changed because of a Prettier philosophy, see: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5641

but you can change formatting of HTML files from Prettier to VS Code's formatter by adding in settings:

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
```

like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646608/3248254

Answer (score 0):

Its working like this with liveserver. But when ı run `npx prettier --write .` . Closed all "input" and "img" tags.

```
{ 
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  "liveServer.settings.port": 5539,
  "liveServer.settings.root": "/public/", 
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last statement? What happens to the tags and when?