# stop tag being self-closing solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint

I'm looking for a way to stop self-closing tag like

`<link rel='stylesheet' />`

to

`<link re='stylesheet'></link>`.

It's always become self-closing.
I tried to remove save action in settting.json and add

```
"react/self-closing-comp": ["error", {
  "component": false,
  "html": false
}]
```

into `tslint.json`, but it still not working.

Comment: when does it become self closing? Upon running formatting? Upon autocompletion? (if so- at what point- after typing what?)

Comment: Why? A [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) element *is* an empty, void element and has no closing tag, from MDN: "*As it is a void element, the start tag must be present and the end tag must not be present.*"

Comment: The reason is Prettier.
Turn it off on settings.json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105287/how-to-stop-prettier-from-using-the-old-self-closing-tag-syntax